# How to run mutliple tasks at once and add return values to a list?

Tags: c#, task, task-parallel-library, taskfactory

What is the easiest way to run multiple [tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task?view=net-6.0) at once and add their return values to a list in c sharp?
I tried a couple ways but I am probably doing everything wrong therefore I don't have much code to post on here.

UPDATE:

Here is one of my fail tries. I am basically trying to get the JSON dictionary from a link (links will be different for each task) and add all the JSON dictionaries to a single list at the end. But I want all the tasks to run at the same time.

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        List<dynamic> writeList = new List<dynamic>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= 50; i++)
        {
            Task<dynamic> task = Task<dynamic>.Factory.StartNew(
                () => savePageData("www.someJsonlink.com"));
            writeList.Add(task);
        }
    }

    static dynamic savePageData(string url)
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        string page = client.DownloadString(url);
        var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(page);
        return data;

    }
}
```

The problem with this approach is that nothing gets added to the list. Actually no connection is made to the link either. But when done normally, the data is present.

Comment: As a side note, instead of `Task<dynamic>.Factory.StartNew` is preferable: `Task.Run`. You can read about the differences between these two methods [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/task-run-vs-task-factory-startnew/ "Task.Run vs Task.Factory.StartNew").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to use the [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select) LINQ operator, combined with the [`Task.WhenAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall) method:

```
int[] ids = GetIds();
Task<Image>[] tasks = ids.Select(id => DownloadImageAsync(id)).ToArray();
Image[] results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

In this example the `Select` operator projects each `int` to a `Task<Image>`, resulting in an `IEnumerable<Image>` sequence. This sequence is materialized to an array of `Task<Image>` by using the `ToArray` LINQ operator.

If the method you are calling for each image is not asynchronous, then instead of `.Select(id => DownloadImageAsync(id))` you can do this:
`.Select(id => Task.Run(() => DownloadImage(id)))`. This way multiple `DownloadImage` will be called in parallel, using `ThreadPool` threads. The number of threads in the pool is limited, so most likely you won't get the same degree of parallelism with what you would get with the truly asynchronous `DownloadImageAsync` invocations.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little on line 2 and line 3? my understanding is that we get a list of `int` and then in line 2 we use each value in that list to create a task (number of tasks will correspond to `ids.Count`?) finally in line 3 we gather all the return values and put them in one single list when all the tasks are done. am I correct?

Comment: I also updated the question if you wouldn't mind taking another look at it.

Comment: @Mahdi_J yes, that's exactly what this code snippet does. The final results are equal in number, and in the same order, as the original ids.

Comment: Thank you. can you think of another approach which is closer to mine (I updated the question)? because I am not very familiar with c# and as easy as your approach is, frankly I have a hard time wrapping my head around it.

Comment: @Mahdi_J in your own example you just need to add this line at the end of the `Main` method: `var results = Task.WhenAll(writeList).Result;`. The `results` is an array of `dynamic` objects.

Comment: @Mahdi_J ah, also the type of the `writeList` should be `List<Task<dynamic>>`, not `List<dynamic>`.